# How can I initialize a python-like list and write to a file in c++

Tags: python, c++, list, file, translate

I have this code in python that I have to translate in c++, but I'm stuck because I can't figure out how I cant initialize a list like that in python and how I can write in a file like the code below

```
def to_file(sy, ey, sx, ex, name, dor):
    rBloc = ["LINE\n", "8\n", str(dor) + "\n",
             "10\n" + str(sx) + "\n" + "11\n" + str(ex) + "\n" +
             "20\n" + str(sy) + "\n" + "21\n" + str(ey) + "\n" +
             "0\n"]
    with open(files.result_directory + r"\box_" + name[:-1] + ".dxf", "a") as f:
        for i in rBloc:
            f.write(str(i))
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question a bit? Are you saying you want to create a std::vector with elements based on the contents of the file you wrote to in Python?

Comment: yes exactly, but what I am looking for is if someone can translate this code and then explain me how he did

Comment: Suggestion: since it looks like you are building a string to write to a file the list seems redundant. Why not just write to the file? `file<< "LINE\n8\n"<<dor << "\n10\n" << sx << "\n11\n" << str(ex) + "\n20\n" << sy << "\n21\n" << ey << "\n0\n"`?

Comment: @user4581301 OP likely didn't do that because bitshifting is hard

Comment: No bitshifting here. That's the [C++ stream insertion operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/) in action. No need for calls to `to_string`, it converts and writes known types directly. No need for `string`, `vector`, or anything else. It just turns everything into the target's default character encoding, probably ASCII, and writes it to the file. [Here's some more detailed documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a C++ vector to replace a list in python. The whole code will look like this.

```
int dor=5,ex=10,sx=20,sy=30,ey=50;
vector<std::string> rBloc{ "LINE\n", "8\n", std::to_string(dor) + "\n",
             "10\n" + std::to_string(sx) + "\n" + "11\n" + std::to_string(ex) + "\n" +
             "20\n" + std::to_string(sy) + "\n" + "21\n" + std::to_string(ey) + "\n" +
             "0\n" };

ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("example.txt");
for(int i=0;i<rBloc.size();i++) {
    myfile << rBloc[I] <<std::endl;
}
myfile.close();
```

Comment: when I opened the file, I saw that there is not carriage return displayed on the console, does this mean that I have to put it in the string or the language do it himself  (i.e "LINE\n") ?

Comment: Do you have initialized the variables dor, sx, ex etc in your code?

Comment: I have changed the code assuming dor, ex, sx, sy, ey are some integers and assigned some random value to them. You can try it now.

Comment: Use myfile << rBloc[i] << std::endl; to print carriage return.

Comment: yeah thanks I have made the changes by myself ! thanks for the quick and great answer

Comment: A quick note: `std::endl` is more than just a carriage return. It's a whole newline PLUS an instruction to flush the stream's buffered data to the underlying media. Flushing can be expensive, so you probably only want to one at the end.